# stop code for X seconds, then continue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How can I stop code for a few seconds and then continue?
I have a page in a `navbar` that only admins can enter. If you're not an admin, I want to have an alert of

> You must be an admin to enter

And then the user will be Redirected to the home page. The code:

```
if (Session["user"] == null)
{
     Response.Write("<script>alert('You must be an admin to get into this page')</script>");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
     Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
}
```

But whats happening is when I press the page in the `navbar` it waits five seconds and redirects me but never alerts me anything. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Response.AddHeader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327(v=vs.90).aspx) like this:

```
if (Session["user"] == null)
{
   Response.Write("<script>alert('You must be an admin to get into this page')</script>");
   Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "5;URL=index.aspx");
}
```